# MQTT vs MQTT over websocket in react native

Tags: react-native, mqtt, mqtt-over-websockets

I am a little bit confused about what extra functionality MQTT over WebSocket provides vs traditional MQTT over TCP in react native. Is MQTT over WebSocket a solution for browsers in order to receive an event in real-time or it adds something more that I can't catch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MQTT over Websockets provides 2 main capabilities over native MQTT.

1. Allows browser based systems to connect to brokers and publish/subscribe to messages. This is because the browser's sandbox doesn't allow native socket operations.
2. Allows MQTT applications to make use of existing proxy set ups. MQTT over Websocket connections can be made through HTTP proxies in situations where other traffic is blocked by a local firewal.